# Which is better way to authenticate an iframe hosted at different domain?

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to render a small web form on client's website, who consumes my services. So there are two things 
1. client's website (hosted at X domain)
2. my services (hosted at Y domain)

As mentioned above via that web form on client's website (from X domain) a user can submit a query on my server (to Y domain).

Note: client's domain must be authenticated, that whether he is eligible to consume the service or not.

So I have implemented the above stuff through an iframe.
I just provided a simple html line (see below) to my clients:

```
<iframe src="Y Domain/myservice?token=AnEncryptedToken"></iframe>
```

And to validate at server side (at Y domain), I am just fetching client's domain by `UrlReferrer.Authority` and comparing the token (decrypted).
So by comparing I can authenticate the current request by knowing its domain, whether its a registered client or not (in my database).

**So now I want to ask is there any better way to this ?**

Because as I searched there are a lot more products on internet, having the same scenario, But they are doing it in another way, They provide some javascript code to their client to render dynamic js file and then they render the iframe (with src="blank") with its html content through that js file.

So am I on the right track ?

Comment: Afraid I'm not experienced enough to comment on whether or not that's a good solution. Though I'd like to mention this likely will not work in IE. IE blocks Iframe from other domains on a default, to prevent cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: Ok. Then I should go with the other one. But I am not sure how efficiently I can implement that. any suggestion ?